Displaying figures as vector graphics with Makie in Julia
I am using the Makie library for visualization in Julia. Whenever I display my figure (by running display(fig)), it opens an image viewer with a png image. Can I somehow get this to instead show me a vector image? Or is there an alternative to display which can do this? (Previously I have been using PyPlot which does this by default)
I know I can save the figure as pdf/svg and open it separately, but is kind of tedious to do every time I want to inspect my figure.
EDIT: I am using Cairo Makie backend. It can create a pdf/svg file when saving, but does not do so, when just (pre)viewing the figure.
EDIT2: I am running julia from terminal, by running julia, and then manually including and running my code into the live julia session.
I tried looking into the definition of display function in the source code of CairoMakie; if I add the configuration stuff (such as type = "pdf", px_per_unit = 10), it is indeed in the configuration, but the type option does not change anything, presumably because (from terminal) I am not inlining the figure. (Not sure what inline actually means in this context, that is what it is called in the code...) The px_per_unit option works though.

What Makie backend are you using?

Try CairoMakie, that should give you vector graphics.

edited the question to say I am in fact using CairoMakie backend

If you are using CairoMakie, you should be able to swich from png to svg if your system's software (your IDE, eg VS Code, etc) is already set up to be able to display svg. You would call
CairoMakie.activate!(type = "svg")
See also https://docs.makie.org/v0.21/explanations/backends/cairomakie.
If you are not using a graphics-enabled IDE and your OS does not have command line support for SVG file display, you can use ElectronDisplay.jl as mentioned here: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/displaying-an-svg-without-a-notebook/82684
So, you ]add ElectronDisplay to Julia's packages, then add
using ElectronDisplay

to the program.

And if I am not using an IDE? I run julia from terminal directly. I tried passing type = "svg" to the display function or to CairoMakie.activate!, but that does not work in terminal. I tried the other options the docs offer (px_per_unit) and those work though. I also tried passing type = "svg" to Makie.set_theme! but that just broke everyting

can you run an svg at the display terminal? It should at least open in browser.

I found one solution to your command-line svg issue on DIscourse, and added it above.
